# getting browserify-shim to work as expected

Tags: node.js, gulp, browserify

I am trying to get browserify-shim to work, but I can't seem to get it to create the globals I expect to see.

*(note, my end goal is to get this working from gulp, but after having many problems, I figured I would eliminate one variable and try to get this working in browserify alone)*

In this case, I expect "horses" to be created as a global variable pointing to the jQuery library.

```
// package.json

{
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "browser": {
    "jquery": "./lib/js/vendor/jquery-2.0.2.js"
  },
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [
      "browserify-shim"
    ]
  },
  "browserify-shim": {
    "jquery": "global:horses"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    // my dev dependencies
  },
  "dependencies": {
    // my production dependencies
  }
}
```

With this configuration, from the command line I run:

```
browserify common.js > mycoolfile.js
```

I then include `mycoolfile.js` into my application and run it in the browser:

```
<script src="mycoolfile.js"></script>
```

The browserified file is included fine, but when I go to chrome dev tools console and type "horses" I get an undefined error. Any thoughts on what I may be doing wrong? Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that you want to get at jquery via `exports` and you are also assuming that `global` lets you take a global a module creates and make an alias for it, but I don't think it does that. The above might work if jquery really did have a global called `horses` it creates, but it won't if you just make up that name arbitrarily. I think you are trying to do something more like this:

```
"browserify-shim": {
  "jquery": {"exports": "jQuery"}
},
```

Comment: Thanks Peter. Your comment and reading through the documentation a few more times helped me land on the setup that worked for me. For future thread visitors, this is the relevant portion of the browserify-shim docs: https://github.com/thlorenz/browserify-shim#multi-shim-example-including-dependencies